# No datable options are showing when angular datatable is implemented?

Tags: angular, datatables, angular6

I tried to implement Angular datatable from this [tutorial](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config)

I have done everything as tld by the tutorail but when i load my table no datatable features are shown.. just plain table!

I added table like:

```
<table datatable class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
```

Its angular 6 project and no errors where found after installing angular-databale!

In console i got this error:

> TypeError: $(_this.el.nativeElement).DataTable is not a function. (In
>   '$(_this.el.nativeElement).DataTable(dtOptions)',
>   '$(_this.el.nativeElement).DataTable' is undefined)

Comment: Did you configure correctly the app.module, the angular.json and all npm dependecies ?

Comment: @AriguiAhmed .. yes i did!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not installed jquery and all dependencies properly. Install dependency as following:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

Also include jQuery & datatable in `scripts` in `angular.json` as:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
]
```

You can find more details [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)

Comment: Yes! I installed everything as told in the documentation!

Comment: @CpKarthik can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I am not familier with stackblitz but i maanged to create it plz look into it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cktvdc

Comment: Previously i installled `datatables.net-bs` will that be an issue?

Comment: it shouldn't. can you try by adding 
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}` in tsconfig.json

Comment: No it didnt worked! Now the complete project has errors! `Module not found`